# Need help with Fisher exact test on SPSS!

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I have a question regarding using the fisher exact test on SPSS.

I am comparing two groups of people in a study. Group 1 has (n=17) people and group 2 has (n=16) people, these people are randomly allocated to the two groups.

If say I observe that group 1 has 1 person who got cancer, and group 2 has none, and I want to know the p value to see if this is statistically significant, I got a p=1 in SPSS. However, if alternatively, I observe that group 2 has 1 person with cancer and group 1 has none, the p value I got (for 2-tailed fisher exact test) is 0.485.

It just seems really odd to me that the difference is so big between the two p values, and I don't know if I did something wrong, of maybe I should not have used this test altogether.